# heroku issue : expected "{", was "$grayMediumLigh..."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm following rails tutorial chapter7, everything went well until when i pushed codes to heroku and pressing the "heroku open" command. then try to run command `$ heroku logs` ,got below error message

```
2013-05-31T16:00:17.416309+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered static_pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (0.5ms)
2013-05-31T16:00:17.431511+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-05-31T16:00:17.431511+00:00 app[web.1]:     3:   <head>
2013-05-31T16:00:17.429902+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 14ms
2013-05-31T16:00:17.431511+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (Invalid CSS after "5: ": expected "{", was "$grayMediumLigh..."
2013-05-31T16:00:17.431511+00:00 app[web.1]:   (in /app/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css)):
2013-05-31T16:00:17.431511+00:00 app[web.1]:     2: <html>
2013-05-31T16:00:17.431761+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-05-31T16:00:17.431511+00:00 app[web.1]:     4:     <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
2013-05-31T16:00:17.431511+00:00 app[web.1]:     6:     <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
2013-05-31T16:00:17.431511+00:00 app[web.1]:     5:     <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all" %>
2013-05-31T16:00:17.431511+00:00 app[web.1]:     7:     <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
2013-05-31T16:00:17.431511+00:00 app[web.1]:     8:     <%= render 'layouts/shim' %>    
2013-05-31T16:00:17.431761+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___1044640585478715857_42045460'
2013-05-31T16:00:17.431761+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-05-31T16:00:18.589737+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=shrouded-waters-7990.herokuapp.com fwd="106.147.82.192" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=304 bytes=0
```

my source file is as follows :

```
application.html.erb

<!DOCTYPE html>                                                              
<html>                                                                       
  <head>                                                                     
    <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>                          
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all" %>                
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>                              
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>                                                    
    <%= render 'layouts/shim' %>                                             
  </head>                                                                    
  <body>                                                                     
    <%= render 'layouts/header' %>                                           
    <div class="container">                                                  
      <% flash.each do |key, value| %>                                       
        <%= content_tag(:div, value, class: "alert alert-#{key}") %>         
      <% end %>                                                              
      <%= yield %>                                                           
      <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>                                         
      <%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>                         
    </div>                                                                   
  </body>                                                                    
</html>
```

`$grayMediumLight` exists in file `custom.css.scss` file. it's too verbose, so i just paste a part as below:

```
custom.css.scss

@import "bootstrap";                   

/* mixins, variables, etc. */          

$grayMediumLight: #eaeaea;             

@mixin box_sizing {                    
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;         
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;      
  box-sizing: border-box;              
}                                      
/* universal */                        

html {                                 
  overflow-y: scroll;                                                                            
}                                      

body {                                 
  padding-top: 60px;                   
}                                      
.....
```

Comment: do you have a link for the tutorial? The code looks correct.

Comment: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-up,this is the link. and i have also pushed my code to https://github.com/ryuever/sample_app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Providing you have resolved the issue, you then need to re-run `bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production` so that the assets can be compiled. As you may find that when you look in your `public/assets/custom.css.scss` the change hasn't been made. So once you precompile your assets using the command provided and push to the Heroku master branch this should resolve your issue.

Comment: It doesn't work. btw, i can't find the file `public/assets/custom.css.scss`, in that folder it is just only three file like **application-fe10468cdb685128eba66fc59c536a77.js**

Comment: @oda when you say it doesn't work, are you referring to `bundle exec assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production` ? I believe usually when you do precompile your assets you should end up with an `application.css` file like so http://i.imgur.com/tGwKl6c.png

Comment: sorry for making you confused, I mean even though i have recompile as you said(may be it should be `bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production` ), but this issue is still not resolved. Then i found all the statements are commented out in file `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css`

Comment: all of a sudden, i found this precompile is aborted with the message `Invalid CSS after "5: ": expected "{", was "$grayMediumLigh..."
  (in /home/ryu/rails_projects/sample_app/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css)`

Comment: sorry, buddy. i don't know how did i get a file `custom.css.css` in folder /app/assets/stylesheets/, then i just delete this file, and pre-compile as you said. then this issue got resolved..

Comment: That's what I exactly meant by image that I posted you earlier. Glad your issue is resolved